# Can I use the internal storage in the Wildfire S to store music and photos?

Tags: camera, storage, htc-wildfire-s

I have a Wildfire S for a couple of weeks while my actual phone is off for repair. I can't use the camera or anything like that because it just says "Insert SD Card". If I look at the storage I can see there is plenty available.

I don't want to buy an SD card just for this temporary phone - my Galaxy S2 has never had this problem.

Can I use the ample internal storage available or will I have to shell out?

Comment: You need to setup the camera to save the photos on the internal storage. It's probably set for external SD card, which is not available.

Comment: As Alex wrote: Open the camera app, and check its settings. It should contain a "storage" section. If it does not (which is the case sometimes), there's no much chance -- except trying some other camera app.

Answer (score 0):

The Wildfire S only has 512MB of internal flash.  None of this austere allotment is allocated to a user storage partition like is done on the Galaxy S2, S3, etc.